# Displaying date from databse in something like dynamically created TextViews on android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, dynamic, textview

I have this code in android that prints data from database to log.

```
List<Message> messages = db.getAllMessages();

for (Message mg : messages) 
{
  String log = "Id: "+mg.getID()+", Message: " + mg.getMessage() + ", Time: " + mg.getDate();
  // display everything on log
  Log.d("", log);
}
```

Is there any way on android that lets me display these data on something like dynamically generated TextViews ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `ListView` with a `CursorAdapter`.
In this szenario your `db.getAllMessages()` should return just a `Cursor` which you'd use with the `CursorAdapter`.